# Error when trying to build module scope express node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules

I am trying to build one of my previous backend project to learn about GitHub actions, however some errors appear when I run webpack.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js 43:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3' in '/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js 76:14-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js 112:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nock' in '/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'
```

The obvious solution would be to remove `"type": "module"` from package.json and change all import from the backend, but I would like to experiment a bit with this scope on a backend project.

Here is my webpack.config.js that I got from [this tutorial](https://its-amit.medium.com/how-to-make-build-for-express-js-node-js-using-webpack-and-deployment-on-docker-9cd219ba24a2)

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);


export default  {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'final.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
};
```

Comment: I solved some of the error by importing the modules required by the node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for all of these errors.

For the first error, I needed to add a new rule to the config file like so:

**webpack.config.js**

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default  {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'final.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      }
    ]
  },
  target: 'node',
};
```

More details on [this page](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/)

For the last three errors, I simply needed to add the dependencies required by the error.
So in this case:

```
npm i mock-aws-s3 aws-sdk nock
```